# Trying to see if one items in a list are in another

Tags: python, list

So here i have two lists

```
cons=['qwe','wer','ert','rty','tyu','yui','uio','iop','asd','sdf','dfg',
      'fgh','ghj','hjk','jkl','zxc','xcv','cvb','vbn','bnm']

print([i for e in alphabet for i in cons if e in i])
```

Alphabet is a user input

If the user were to type, for example, qwe, then the shell would print `'qwe','wer','ert','rty'` (all items that have at least one letter similar) BUT i only want it to print the items from cons if of all items from the input are similar to that. E.g, print 'qwe'

How do i do this?

EDIT: to make this more clear, if i were to input 'qwer', i would like the outputs to be 'qwe' and 'wer'

Comment: It's unclear what your desired output is. Do you want to print elements that consist only of letters that are also in the user's input?

Comment: You must take a look to the `itertools` package.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "similar to that" means in your question.  For example, does Alphabet need to be an exact match?  Or does simply each letter from alphabet need to be in the substrings from the list `cons`?  Will there be duplicates in any of the strings?  Will the strings vary in length?  It's hard to help with a solution when all these questions are unanswered.

Comment: if i was to input 'qwer', I would like the output to be 'qwe', and 'wer', it has to be an exact match. Sorry for late reply

Comment: `'qwer'` and `'qwe'` are not exact matches.  Do you mean that you want results only for the strings in cons if they exist exactly as a match as a substring from the alphabet?  i.e. `'qwe'` is a substring of `'qwer'`

Comment: but qwe and wer are in qwer

Comment: So that means they are substrings; therefore, the 'exact match' language you want to use would refer to a string in `cons` matching a *substring* from alphabet.  I updated my answer to include this requirement you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cons=['qwe','wer','ert','rty','tyu','yui','uio','iop','asd','sdf','dfg',
      'fgh','ghj','hjk','jkl','zxc','xcv','cvb','vbn','bnm']
```

**UPDATE** (based on OP comments) *If you need the strings in `cons` to be exact match substrings of `alphabet`*, then this code simply checks if the string from  `cons` is a substring of `alphabet` (exact match) and includes it if so:

```
print([sub for sub in cons if sub in alphabet])
```

for case: `alphabet` = `'qwer'`, ouput = `['qwe', 'wer']`

However, based on the OP, this test checks if all the letters in the strings of `cons` exist in the `alphabet` (not necessarily in exact order and frequency).  This uses the `all()` method which returns `True` if all arguments passed are `True`.

```
print([sub for sub in cons if all(let in alphabet for let in sub)])
```

Explanation: `let in alphabet` returns True or False based on whether each letter, `let`, is in the user input string, `alphabet`.  This is executed for each letter in the sub string of `cons`, `for let in sub`.  Therefore each letter from the user input will be checked and only evaluate to `True` if all letters from the `sub` string are in the alphabet.  If this check evaluates to True, than the substring is included in the results and printed.  This function works if the substrings from `con` are of different lengths from the user input, `alphabet`.

If alphabet = `'er'`, output = `[]` (no strings have all letters in `alphabet`)

If alphabet = `'qwer'`, output = `['qwe', 'wer']`

Comment: if i was to input 'qwer', I would like the output to be 'qwe', and 'wer'

Comment: Okay, I updated answer based on your updated requirements.  There are still a lot of unanswered questions.  If you need more help, you need to be more specific about what your code is trying to accomplish and use more examples of why you need the code to do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

did you find it?:

```
print ([x for x in cons  if sorted(list(x)) == sorted(list(alphabet))])
```

or if need to find not complete coincidence

```
print ([x for x in cons  if ''.join(sorted(list(alphabet))) in ''.join(sorted(list(x)))])
```

Comment: `sorted(list(x)) == sorted(list(alphabet))` What happens if alphabet is shorter in length than the x string from cons?  Wouldn't this conditional not include such a case since the strings would not be equal length (therefore not equal lists)?  However, I think the OP wants such a case to be included.

Comment: i added for second case, but i'm not sure that need include.

Comment: Yes, the second case you added would account for such an input, nice fix!

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you don't care about the order of the output strings in your list, then you could of course do:

```
inputs = ['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty', 'tyu', 'yui', 'uio', 'iop', 'asd', 'sdf',
          'dfg', 'fgh', 'ghj', 'hjk', 'jkl', 'zxc', 'xcv', 'cvb', 'vbn', 'bnm']

def string_intersections(input_string):

    def intersect(string):
        input_letters = set(input_string)
        string_letters = set(string)
        has_intersection = input_letters == string_letters
        return has_intersection

    result = list(filter(intersect, inputs))
    return result

string_intersections("boo")
```

Comment: Using sets was probably an overkill here, and makes it less general than it should be though.

Answer (score 0):

try with `set`:

```
cons=['qwe','wer','ert','rty','tyu','yui','uio','iop','asd','sdf','dfg',
      'fgh','ghj','hjk','jkl','zxc','xcv','cvb','vbn','bnm']
alphabet = "weq"
print([c for c in cons if set(alphabet).issubset(set(c))]) # output will be ['qwe']
```

Comment: if i was to input 'qwer', I would like the output to be 'qwe', and 'wer'. The item i type has to match identically to a list item